# Generate id row for a view with grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, window-functions, sql-view

I'm trying to create a view with row numbers like so:

```
create or replace view daily_transactions as
select 
    generate_series(1, count(t)) as id,        
    t.ic,
    t.bio_id,
    t.wp,    
    date_trunc('day', t.transaction_time)::date transaction_date, 
    min(t.transaction_time)::time time_in, 
    w.start_time wp_start,    
    w.start_time - min(t.transaction_time)::time in_diff,    
    max(t.transaction_time)::time time_out,     
    w.end_time wp_end,    
    max(t.transaction_time)::time - w.end_time out_diff,     
    count(t) total_transactions,
    calc_att_status(date_trunc('day', t.transaction_time)::date,
                    min(t.transaction_time)::time,
                    max(t.transaction_time)::time,
                    w.start_time, w.end_time ) status        
from transactions t
left join wp w  on (t.wp = w.wp_name)
group by ic, bio_id, t.wp, date_trunc('day', transaction_time),
         w.start_time, w.end_time;
```

I ended up with duplicate rows. `SELECT DISTINCT` doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Transaction Table:

```
create table transactions(
    id serial primary key,    
    ic text references users(ic),
    wp text references wp(wp_name),
    serial_no integer,    
    bio_id integer,
    node integer,
    finger integer,
    transaction_time timestamp,    
    transaction_type text,        
    transaction_status text        
 );
```

WP table:

```
create table wp(
    id serial unique,   
    wp_name text primary key,
    start_time time,
    end_time time,
    description text,
    status text    
);
```

View Output:

[image: View Output]

Comment: can you provide the schema and some sample data for the transactions and wp tables?

Comment: @TetonSig I have added the table definitions and sample data. Thanks for looking at my question :)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  Can you provide a few sample records from each table for a specific wp_name from wp and matching wp from transactions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW daily_transactions as
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id
     , t.ic
     , t.bio_id
     , t.wp 
     , t.transaction_time::date AS transaction_date
     , min(t.transaction_time)::time AS time_in
     , w.start_time AS wp_start
     , w.start_time - min(t.transaction_time)::time AS in_diff
     , max(t.transaction_time)::time AS time_out
     , w.end_time AS wp_end
     , max(t.transaction_time)::time - w.end_time AS out_diff
     , count(*) AS total_transactions
     , calc_att_status(t.transaction_time::date, min(t.transaction_time)::time
                     , max(t.transaction_time)::time
                     , w.start_time, w.end_time) AS status
FROM   transactions t
LEFT   JOIN wp w ON t.wp = w.wp_name
GROUP  BY t.ic, t.bio_id, t.wp, t.transaction_time::date
        , w.start_time, w.end_time;
```

#### Major points

- `generate_series()` is a plain (set-returning) function, applied after aggregate functions. It produces **multiple rows**, thereby multiplying all output rows.
  The [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) is also applied after aggregate functions, but only generates a **single number per row**.
- `date_trunc()` is redundant in `date_trunc('day', t.transaction_time)::date`. `t.transaction_time::date` achieves the same, simpler & faster.
- Use `count(*)` instead of `count(t)`. Same result here, but a bit faster.

Some other minor changes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: congratulations for 10k ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Thank you it works flawlessly! Great explanation too.

Comment: Hello... supposing you want the ids for pagination in the server... would that do the trick ? Or do we need a materialized view ?

Comment: @yucer: If you want it fast, you need index support, and that requires materialized IDs. So add a column to the tabler (if possible!), or use a materialized view. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I didn't want it fast but accurate. I mean the same values if queried from similar views depending on the same objects (transactions and wp in this case).

I ended with row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY true) like here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/postgresql-create-view-with-autoincremental-column/190979#190979

Comment: @yucer: as for "accurate": make sure the `ORDER BY` of `row_number()` is deterministic, and there cannot be any writes to the colums defining that order during operation, else the order breaks.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter for me `PARTITION by true` makes the trick of the same numeration from different views. Do you know why ?

Comment: @yucer: `PARTITION by true` is just noise. Same as without any partition.