# Optimize query with OFFSET on large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.5

I have table

```
create table big_table (
id serial primary key,
-- other columns here
vote int
);
```

This table is very big, approximately 70 million rows, I need to query:

```
SELECT * FROM big_table
ORDER BY vote [ASC|DESC], id [ASC|DESC]
OFFSET x LIMIT n  -- I need this for pagination
```

As you may know, when `x` is a large number, queries like this are very slow.

For performance optimization I added indexes:

```
create index vote_order_asc on big_table (vote asc, id asc);
```

and

```
create index vote_order_desc on big_table (vote desc, id desc);
```

`EXPLAIN` shows that the above `SELECT` query uses these indexes, but it's very slow anyway with a large offset.

What can I do to optimize queries with `OFFSET` in big tables? Maybe PostgreSQL 9.5 or even newer versions have some features? I've searched but didn't find anything.

Comment: why not keyset pagination?  http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan This method have some disadvantages, for example only previous and next pages , but it seems I forced to choice this way

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A large `OFFSET` is always going to be slow. Postgres has to order all rows and count the *visible* ones up to your offset. To skip all previous rows ***directly*** you could add an indexed `row_number` to the table (or create a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) including said `row_number`) and work with `WHERE row_number > x` instead of `OFFSET x`.

However, this approach is only sensible for read-only (or mostly) data. Implementing the same for table data that can change *concurrently* is more challenging. You need to start by defining desired behavior *exactly*.

I suggest a different approach, sometimes called **"keyset pagination"**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   big_table
WHERE  (vote, id) > (vote_x, id_x)  -- ROW values
ORDER  BY vote, id  -- needs to be deterministic
LIMIT  n;
```

Where `vote_x` and `id_x` are from the *last* row of the ***previous page*** (for both `DESC` and `ASC`). Or from the *first* if navigating *backwards*.

Comparing row values is supported by the index you already have - a feature that complies with the ISO SQL standard, but not every RDBMS supports it.

```
CREATE INDEX vote_order_asc ON big_table (vote, id);
```

Or for descending order:

```
SELECT *
FROM   big_table
WHERE  (vote, id) < (vote_x, id_x)  -- ROW values
ORDER  BY vote DESC, id DESC
LIMIT  n;
```

Can use the same index.
I suggest you declare your columns `NOT NULL` or acquaint yourself with the `NULLS FIRST|LAST` construct:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Note **two things** in particular:

1. The `ROW` values in the `WHERE` clause cannot be replaced with separated member fields. `WHERE (vote, id) > (vote_x, id_x)` ***cannot*** be replaced with:

```
WHERE  vote >= vote_x
AND    id   > id_x
```

That would rule out *all* rows with `id <= id_x`, while we only want to do that for the same vote and not for the next. The correct translation would be:

```
    WHERE (vote = vote_x AND id > id_x) OR vote > vote_x
```

... which doesn't play along with indexes as nicely, and gets increasingly complicated for more columns.

Would be simple for a *single* column, obviously. That's the special case I mentioned at the outset.

2. The technique does not work for mixed directions in `ORDER BY` like:

   ```
    ORDER  BY vote ASC, id DESC
   ```

At least I can't think of a *generic* way to implement this as efficiently. If at least one of both columns is a numeric type, you could use a functional index with an inverted value on `(vote, (id * -1))` - and use the same expression in `ORDER BY`:

```
    ORDER  BY vote ASC, (id * -1) ASC
```

Related:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)
- [Improve performance for order by with columns from many tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112680/3684)

Note in particular the presentation by Markus Winand I linked to:

- ["Pagination done the PostgreSQL way"](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way)

Comment: how about jump to a random page?@Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: @Dolphin: In a read-only setting, rather add an indexed row number. For read-mostly, a materialized view with a row number. Under concurrent write load, "pages" are a moving target. You might "jump" to a page number with `OFFSET`, but jumping back might send you to a different page ...

Comment: Interesting approach. So it seems to me that the primary id could be used in the filtering as well(?). Initially the parameter value would be (0 or negative), and then when clicking getting the next page, simply passing the largest primary ID value from the current page(?)

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried partioning the table ?

> Ease of management, improved scalability and availability, and a
>   reduction in blocking are common reasons to partition tables.
>   Improving query performance is not a reason to employ partitioning,
>   though it can be a beneficial side-effect in some cases. In terms of
>   performance, it is important to ensure that your implementation plan
>   includes a review of query performance. Confirm that your indexes
>   continue to appropriately support your queries after the table is
>   partitioned, and verify that queries using the clustered and
>   nonclustered indexes benefit from partition elimination where
>   applicable.
>
> http://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/sql-indexes/partitioning-benefits

Comment: That is for SQL Server, not for Postgres

Comment: PostgreSQL supports basic table partitioning : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html