# Couchbase - Large offset performance

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

Working on **paging** data around 100k doc on Couchbase.
It work quite well around first 1k, but it turn to be slower and slower on bigger offset.

I have read [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34110504/3374136) and I'm not sure it will be suitable for apply on Couchbase OR is Couchbase have another better/easier solution ?

Thanks for suggestion

Sincerely,

Liratanak

Comment: I have noticed similar issues with skip and offset. It is like it is reading the entire query set and then only returning the number it needs to, but still scanning through the items to be skipped. I'm not sure if others have noticed this or not.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the upcoming release of Couchbase and N1QL. A developer preview will be available in spring 2016, followed by Beta and GA releases. The tracking issue is at https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-17202.