# Conditional offset on union select

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, plpgsql, query-performance

Consider we have complex union select from dozens of tables with different structure but similar fields meaning:

```
SELECT a1.abc as field1,
       a1.bcd as field2,
       a1.date as order_date,
FROM a1_table a1
UNION ALL
SELECT a2.def as field1,
       a2.fff as field2,
       a2.ts  as order_date,

FROM a2_table a2
UNION ALL ...

ORDER BY order_date
```

Notice also that results in general are sorted by "synthetic" field `order_date`.

This query gives huge number of rows, and we want to work with pages from this set of rows. Each page is defined by two parameters:

- page size
- `field2` value of last item from previous page

Most important thing that **we can not change** the way can page is defined. I.e. it is not possible to use row number of date of last item from previous page: only `field2` value is acceptable.

Current algorithm of paging is implemented in quite ugly way:

1) query above is wrapped in additional select with `row_number()` additional column and then wrapped in stored procedure `union_wrapper` which returns appropriate
   `table ( field1 ..., field2 character varying)`,

2) then complex select performed:

```
 RETURN QUERY
    with tmp as (
      select
        rownum, field1, field2 from union_wrapper()
    )
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM tmp
    WHERE rownum > (SELECT rownum
                    FROM tmp
                    WHERE field2 = last_field_id
                    LIMIT 1)
    LIMIT page_size
```

The problem is that we have to build in memory full union-select results in order to later detect row number from which we want to cut new page. This is quite slow and takes unacceptable much time to perform.

Is any way to reconfigure this operations in order to significantly reduce query complexity and increase its speed?

And again: we can not change condition of paging, we can not change structure of the tables. Only way of rows retrieving.

**UPD**: I also can not use temp tables, because I'm working in read-replica of the database.

Comment: `ORDER BY order_date` <--> `WHERE field2 = last_field_id` I'd expect a highwatermark to be at least the leading part of the ordering/index. And, since your data model is crippled, you could consider a temp table or a marerialised view.

Comment: @joop I can not use temp tables as I'm working in read-replica. Sorry, I didn't mention this in my question, so I will update it

Comment: If you have to use all those `UNION ALL` anyway, I believe `row_number over()` is not that ugly for pagination

Comment: @VaoTsun I do not quite understand your statement, sorry. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: I meant that most of cost comes when you `union all` all tables. and probably next most costy is subselect?.. So I'm saying that using `row_number` here does not see ugly. - Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: @VaoTsun I've never said that `row_number` is core of the problem. Core of the problem is that I have to ask DB build full list of rows and only after that cut page from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully maneuvered yourself into a tight spot. The query and its `ORDER BY` expression contradict your paging requirements.

`ORDER BY order_date` is not a ***deterministic*** sort order (there could be multiple rows with the same `order_date`) - which you *need* before you do anything else here. And `field2` does not seem to be unique either. You need both: Define a deterministic sort order and a unique indicator for page end / start. Ideally, the indicator ***matches*** the sort order. Could be `(order_date, field2)`, which both columns defined `NOT NULL`, and the combination `UNIQUE`. Your restriction *`"only field2 value is acceptable"`* contradicts your query.

That's all *before* thinking about how to get best performance ...

There are proven solutions with row values and multi-column indexes for paging:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

But drawing from a combination of multiple source tables complicates matters. Optimization depends on the details of your setup.

If you can't get the performance you need, your only remaining alternative is to materialize the query results somehow. Temp table, cursor, materialized view - the best tool depends on details of your setup.

[Of course, general performance tuning might help, too.](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization)