# How to gradually print SQL query results before the end of execution?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pagination

I'm doing a pretty big Postgres query. Is it possible to echo the results gradually in spite of waiting for the end of the query to echo all the results?

My code:

```
$sql1 = pg_query("select zhu_gid from indicateurs.note where zhu_gid not in (select gid from public.zh);");

while($data = pg_fetch_array($sql1))
   {
   echo $data['zhu_gid']."/";
   }
```

Comment: I am not sure you can, but if you are using ajax requests to get the results you can add ``LIMIT`` and ``OFFSET`` to the query to get batches of results, and execute it as much times as needed to get it all. Otherwise, in that specific case, PHP will wait for the end of the query before carrying on with the rest of the code

Comment: You can get PHP to flush the output one echo at a time if need be, but it still won't start echoing until the results have all been returned from the database

Answer (score 1):

As to your question: **No.** Postgres itself first builds the result set, then returns to the client.

You could use a [cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) for that (which still has to execute the query successfully first). Or multiple queries, partitioning the result with [`LIMIT` / `OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) or (preferably) deterministic `WHERE` conditions. You need to add a deterministic `ORDER BY` for those. But all of these **pagination** solutions have their specific difficulties. Related:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

Aside, I'd not use `NOT IN`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Consider instead:

```
SELECT n.zhu_gid
FROM   indicateurs.note n
LEFT   JOIN public.zh ON zh.gid = n.zhu_gid
WHERE  zh.gid IS NULL;
```