# Postgresql offset return same data

Tags: postgresql

I have a two tables. I want to do pagination when I call the query result is always same. Where is mistake?

```
select t1.id, status, category, lat, lng
    from public.p t1
join public.l t2 on t1.id=t2.id and user_id=4 limit 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: I doubt that using limit without order by can give random results as mentioned in the PostgreSQL manual.. This is also been defined in the SQL standard SQL tables and resultsets are always **orderless** without order by cause

Comment: But if you want to the next page increase the OFFSET to match your page size

Comment: "Always same" as what? The previous call *without* `OFFSET`? Or the same call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, without `ORDER BY` Postgres is free to return ***any*** rows at all, since the order is undefined and any result is correct. (But Postgres will still apply `OFFSET`, so that should even "work" without `ORDER BY`.)

Retry with a (deterministic) `ORDER BY`:

```
select t1.id, status, category, lat, lng
from public.p t1
join public.l t2 on t1.id=t2.id and user_id=4
ORDER BY ?something?                             -- !
limit 10
offset 10
```

Be that as it may, `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` is typically not the best tool for ***pagination***. See:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)