# Indexing strategy for filters including a JSONB property

Tags: postgresql, pagination, sequelize.js, jsonb, postgresql-performance

I have a `jsonb` column created via `sequelize` migration this way:

```
queryInterface.addColumn('Entities', 'summary', {
  type: Sequelize.DataTypes.JSONB,
})
```

My Postgres version:

> PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

My rows generally have this kind of structure:

```
{ 
  summary: {
    foobar: 123.456
  }
}
```

I need a query that compares a parameter to a property of that JSONB summary:

```
where: {
  summary: {
    foobar: {
      [Sequelize.Op.lt]: parseFloat(maxFoobar),
    },
  },
}
```

Query generated by Sequelize:

```
SELECT "id", "name", "type", "geometry", "summary", "createdAt", "updatedAt"
FROM "Entities" AS "Entity"
WHERE CAST(("Entity"."summary"#>>'{foobar}') AS DOUBLE PRECISION) < 64
ORDER BY "Entity"."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0;
```

With 150,000 rows, this is taking 300-400ms:

```
                                                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=29685.31..29696.98 rows=100 width=1475) (actual time=81.465..85.319 rows=100 loops=1)
   Output: id, name, type, geometry, summary, "createdAt", "updatedAt"
   Buffers: shared hit=91259 read=17301
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=29685.31..34772.56 rows=43602 width=1475) (actual time=81.461..85.310 rows=100 loops=1)
         Output: id, name, type, geometry, summary, "createdAt", "updatedAt"
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=91259 read=17301
         ->  Sort  (cost=28685.29..28739.79 rows=21801 width=1475) (actual time=76.879..76.889 rows=50 loops=3)
               Output: id, name, type, geometry, summary, "createdAt", "updatedAt"
               Sort Key: "Entity"."createdAt" DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 309kB
               Buffers: shared hit=91259 read=17301
               Worker 0:  actual time=75.047..75.062 rows=65 loops=1
                 Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 353kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=29140 read=5589
               Worker 1:  actual time=75.044..75.055 rows=63 loops=1
                 Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 351kB
                 Buffers: shared hit=29074 read=5532
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public."Entities" "Entity"  (cost=0.00..27852.07 rows=21801 width=1475) (actual time=0.184..68.223 rows=20705 loops=3)
                     Output: id, name, type, geometry, summary, "createdAt", "updatedAt"
                     Filter: ((("Entity".summary #>> '{foobar}'::text[]))::double precision < '64'::double precision)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 31618
                     Buffers: shared hit=91145 read=17301
                     Worker 0:  actual time=0.240..66.849 rows=20034 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=29083 read=5589
                     Worker 1:  actual time=0.081..66.737 rows=19791 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=29017 read=5532
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=40
 Planning Time: 0.815 ms
```

How can I build an index on that JSONB key to run the query?

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING and please share the query plan using `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement and the statement itself. (all in plain text)

Comment: in terms of the example you used in your question, to create an index on the numeric value of Entities.summary->foobar you should do `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_summary_foobar ON "Entities" ((summary->>'foobar')::numeric) USING BTREE;`

Comment: @DiegoD With psql (15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1)) I am getting `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"`

Comment: @FrankHeikens I added the query plan. Should the param '64' look like a string as in this plan?

Comment: `Removed by Filter: 94854` and `rows=62114` tells us that a pretty large percentage of rows from your table is returned in the result. Using an index could make the query slower, not faster: The database has to first to use the index and second get the data from the table. And 40% of all data, that's a lot. You might want to lower the setting for random_page_cost, something like 1.1 and see if the planner starts using your index AND to see if it's faster.

Comment: First question that arises: Do you actually need to return 62114 rows with all those listed columns? (Typically, you don't.)

Comment: Correct - I am only pulling a page of 100 rows but I had removed that part of the query to `explain()`. Now I updated with the full query plan including pagination.

Comment: Filtering by one thing, ordering by another, combined with a small `LIMIT` - that's the tricky kind of queries. Please provide information as instructed in the [tag info for  performance questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). You are already half-way there. In particular, note `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)`  and your Postgres version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your filter criteria is not very selective, scanning an index on just `"createdAt"` is certainly a good option. Postgres will find 100 rows to satisfy the query quickly. Inspecting nested values of a JSON document always adds cost (especially if the value is big).

This tailored partial index cuts down on this cost:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON "Entities" ("createdAt" DESC)
WHERE (summary->>'foobar')::float8 < 64;
```

Adding a (redundant) generated column, with the index based on that would help some more:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Entities"
ADD COLUMN foobar float8 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((summary->>'foobar')::float8) STORED;

CREATE INDEX ON "Entities" ("createdAt" DESC)
WHERE foobar < 64;
```

See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Depending on the complete situation and missing information, a more generic index may be good enough - and serve more purposes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON "Entities" ("createdAt");
```

If your pagination goes deep, consider upgrading from `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` to "ROW value comparsion", a.k.a. "keyset pagination". See:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

Comment: That index on createdAt is very effective - thanks! I have been wanting to avoid indices inside the summary and definitely don't want to create another column and I might be able to avoid that now at 100-200ms.